# System.out.println not working after printWriter on System.out

Tags: java, printwriter, system.out

I am facing a rather unusual situation. I am using `printWriter` with `System.out`
to print the bytes from a file onto console, first using a `ByteStreamReader` and then a `CharacterStreamReader`. The problem is after the output of `ByteStreamReader`, subsequent `System.out.println` statements are not printing anything on console. I tried using flush on `System.out.flush()` but still not getting output.

Code:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(); //ByteStreamReader
String source = "./test_zh.txt";
CharacterStream cs = new CharacterStream(); //CharacterStreamReader
System.out.println("\nChinese Sentence using ByteStreamReader");
fs.printOnConsole(source); //if i comment this, then below lines gets printed 
System.out.println("\nChinese Sentence using CharacterStreamReader");//Not getting printed on console
cs.printOnConsole(source); //Not getting printed on console
```

My code for both the Stream types is as follows:

### FileSteam Class

```
public void printOnConsole(String source) throws IOException{
try{
    inp = new FileInputStream(source);
    pwr = new PrintWriter(System.out,true);
    int c =0;

    while( (c = inp.read()) != -1){
        pwr.write(c);
        pwr.write("(" + c +")");
    }
}catch(FileNotFoundException f){

}catch(IOException e){

}finally{
    inp.close();
    pwr.flush();
    pwr.close();

}
}
```

### CharacterStream  Class

```
    public void printOnConsole(String source) throws IOException{
    try{
        fReader = new FileReader(source);
        pwr     = new PrintWriter(System.out,true);
        int c;
        while((c = fReader.read()) != -1){
            pwr.write(c);
            pwr.write("(" +c +")");
        }

    }catch(IOException f){

    }finally{
        fReader.close();
        pwr.flush();
        pwr.close();

    }
    }
```

Comment: what is probably happening is that one of your invocations to `.close()` internally closes the stream that it delegates to, so it closes `System.out`.

Comment: You may have got an exception. Try add `f.printStackTrace()` in all the `catch`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see 2 significant problems with your `FileStream` and `CharacterStream` classes.

- Both classes call `close()` on the `PrintWriter` that wraps `System.out`.  When that happens `System.out` will be closed, and no further writes to it will be permitted.
- Both classes *squash* IO exceptions.  That is they catch the exception, say nothing, and continue as if nothing happened.  That is extremely poor coding practice ... and it is most likely hiding the exceptions that happen when you write to the closed `System.out` stream.

There are also a variety of style problems, the worst of which is your poor choice of method and class names.  For example the printOnConsole methods don't print on the console.  Rather they print on the standard output stream  ... which may go to somewhere other than the console.  (And your application can't tell!!)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: I understood, your first point. Regarding the 2nd point, I was trying to test something and write a very simple program and therefore  didn't bothered to print the exceptions in the catch block, but now since you pointed it out,  I understand it was mistake on my part.

Comment: Here's the thing though: by not "being bothered" to deal with the exceptions properly, you actually ended up with code that behaved in a baffling way and wasted (I'm guessing) hours over it.  A better strategy: if you don't care, then use `throws` to allow the exceptions to propagate.  Silent squashing is almost always a bad idea.